# How to compare numbers in any base

Tags: c++, c, radix

I have been trying to compare two numbers of any base `B` without first changing them into decimal. Is there a way to do it?

I was able to do it by converting them into decimal. This is how i did it (on base 17):

```
 for(i=strlen(s)-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
     if(s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='G')
         s[i]=s[i]-'A'+ 10;
     else
         s[i]=s[i]-'0';

     int z=(int)s[i];

     a+=z*pow(17,j);
     j++;
 }
```

Comment: show what have you tried, what does no work.

Comment: Are they both of the same base, and what is their in-memory representation ?

Comment: Food for thought: Perhaps 'any base' is a bit over-reaching.  How many bases are there? Of course there are more than 17.  Perhaps more than all the letters in the English alphabet?  Perhaps even more than can be represented by all letters of all alphabets of all languages combined? Base 10 requires 10 symbols [0-9]. Hexadecimal requires 16 [0-9,A-F]  What about base 1000? [0-9,A-Z,a-z,???]

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer: You are not restricted to single-digit encoding. You could, for example, use arrays of integers, so that 1,234,567 would become {1, 23, 45, 67} in base 100 and {1, 234, 567} in base 1000.

Comment: @MOehm, of course you are correct.  In any case, some convention to represent digits of a base would have to be established.  Food for thought... is it **'Base 10'** or is it **'Base A'**?

Comment: Actually, you are converting them to binary, because that is the internal representation of `int` in most computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers are compared by their *value*. If their notation is different (in terms of base), digits in the same places means something else. For instance:

```
10 [10] > 1000 [2]
10 [10] < 10000 [2]
```

I guess the only way to compare two values in different bases is to convert them to the common base and compare afterwards.

For given number [image: n] consisting of digits [image: d = d_k d_{k-1} ... d_1 d_0] in a base [image: b], you can evaluate the *value* of number using the following formula:

[image: value = sum_{i=0}^{k} d_{i}*b^i]

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the individual digits:

```
//
// Comparing numbers s1 and s2
//

// If they have different length, they are different
length = strlen(s1);
if (strlen(s2) != length)
    return 0;

// Now compare all digits
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    if (s1[i] != s2[i])
        return 0; // found different digits - numbers are not equal
}
return 1; // all digits are equal - numbers are equal
```

It's possible to make the implementation smaller by not calculating the length of the strings (iterate until terminating null `char` is found).

Comment: I also wanted to know which one of them is greater.

Comment: Just replace `!=` by `>` in the comparisons (but be careful to compare the lengths correctly)